# Where does setup.py install console scripts to?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, setuptools

When I set up my package using setup.py to have a console script entry point, `pip install -e .` creates a cli exe in the `C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\envname`**`\Scripts`**`\foo.exe`.

However on a separate computer the python executable is the one from the Windows Store:

`C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n6khra8p0\python.exe`
This doesn't set the PATH environment variable correctly to make `.exe`s in the Scripts folder callable from the command line, so I need the full path to the .exe to call it.

Anyway I want to find the location of foo.exe on this second computer (which I don't have access to), *is there a command I can instruct the second computer to run which will tell me where a console script will be located* for that given `sys.executable`? I.e. for my computer, I expect it to print `C:\Users\...\anaconda3\envs\envname\Scripts`.

---

FWIW, this is my `setup.cfg`:

```auto
[options]
py_modules = xml2csv
python_requires = >=3.10

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    xml2csv=xml2csv:main
```

Comment: Try `python -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path("scripts"))'`.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out the the solution hoefling pointed out in the comments worked for me.

```bash
python -c 'import sysconfig; print(sysconfig.get_path("scripts"))'
```

In my case when using venv it was installed in `<project>/.venv/bin/<script>`.

---

In my case there already existed another executables in a different path which prioritised over my python `venv/bin`. To check if the correct script is executed you can use:

```bash
which <script>
```

to get the location of the executable (for Linux/Mac).